# Fitch Proof - Arrow's logic of preferences

Tags: logic, proof, symbolic-logic, fitch

I've been stumped on this one question in particular for several days now and I'm hoping to get some help on where I'm going wrong.

**Given the following premises:**

1. ∀x∀y(StrongPref(x,y)→ ¬StrongPref(y,x))
2. ∀x∀y∀z((StrongPref(x,y)∧StrongPref(y,z))→StrongPref(x,z))
3. ∀xIndiff(x,x)
4. ∀x∀y(Indiff(x,y)→Indiff(y,x))
5. ∀x∀y∀z((StrongPref(x,y)∧Indiff(y,z))→StrongPref(x,z))
6. ∀x∀y(StrongPref(x,y)∨Indiff(x,y)∨StrongPref(y,x))
7. ∀x∀y(WeakPref(x,y)↔(StrongPref(x,y)∨Indiff(x,y)))

**Prove:** *(Not required to use all the premises)*

```
∀x∀y∀z((Indiff(x,y) ∧ Indiff(y,z)) → Indiff(x,z))
```

---

Since we are trying to prove a conditional, my initial inclination is to assume `Indiff(x,y) ∧ Indiff(y,z)` and try to prove `Indiff(x,z)`. Since none of the premises explicitly tells us much information about deriving `Indiff`, I figured it would be best to prove by contradition - that is, assuming `~Indiff(x,z)` and deriving a contradiction.

I begin the proof by initializing the quantifiers, using c,d,e in place of x,y,z. Since only premises (5) and (6) give us some information about `Indiff` to work off of, I am thinking to initially use (6) and go through each case/combination of `StrongPref(c,d) ∨ Indiff(c,d) ∨ StrongPref(d,c)`and `StrongPref(d,e) ∨ Indiff(d,e) ∨ StrongPref(e,d)` in order to get `c` and `e` together (which seems unreasonable since that would mean doing 9 proofs but I'm getting desperate). Then, to get the contradictions, I used (5) to derive something of the form StrongPref(x,x) which we can get a contradiction from (1).

I am able to get contradictions for many of the cases, but I begin getting stuck when it comes to getting a contradiction in the case where we have both Indiff(c,d) and Indiff(d,e).

I have shown my work below (took out some of the repeated work for working contradictions to save space). I have a feeling I'm completely off since it seems unreasonable of have to do 9 subproofs, but I can't see another perspective to take. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

[image]

Comment: See your [previous post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/64053/fitch-arrow-proofs).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fitch Arrow Proofs](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/64053/fitch-arrow-proofs)

Comment: Thank you for taking notice - while the linked question uses the same premises/axioms, it's attempting to prove something completely different

This question is asking to prove the transitivity of `Indiff`, whereas the other one is proving something with `StrongPref`

Comment: I agree. I don't see this as a duplicate. +1 for a clear presentation of what you have attempted.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a direct proof. I converted *StrongPref* to *S* and *Indiff* to *I* to use the syntax required by the proof checker associated with *forallx*.

After assuming the antecedent on line 5, I attempted to derive the consequent using premise 4. Premise 4 was a disjunction so I had to eliminate it. In each case I derived *Iac*. When that was done, I introduced the universal quantifiers.

[image]

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf